# Show year only once in archives loop

Tags: php, mysql, date, loops, blogs

I just started with PHP and mySQL and I'm creating some kind of blog. At time I think it's going well - I just got some trouble with my archives code.

I think the solution will be pretty easy but I'm so blinded that I just can't find the point on my own.

This is my actual code and everything works fine, also the links:

```
$sql = mysql_query ("SELECT YEAR(date) AS get_year, MONTH(date) AS get_month, COUNT(*) AS entries FROM blogdata GROUP BY get_month ORDER BY date ASC") or die('No response from database.');


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {

$get_year = $row["get_year"];
$get_month = $row["get_month"];
$entries = $row["entries"];

    // get month name
$this_month = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $row["get_month"]) );



echo '<dl>';
echo '<dt>Entries from &nbsp;'. $get_year . '</dt>';

echo '<dd><a href="archives.php?month='. $get_month .'">Entries from &nbsp;'. $this_month . '&nbsp;</a>(' . $entries . ')</dd>';

echo '</dl>';  

}
```

Ok. Then the result in the browser looks similar like this:

- Entries from  2012

  1. Entries from  January (2)
- Entries from  2012

  1. Entries from  February (1)

Now my question: How can I resume all months inside the year? Like this:

- Entries from  2012

  1. Entries from  January (2)
  2. Entries from  February (1)

I'm scared about creating a 12-months array cause maybe not every month there will be entries, and I don't want to show empty months.

Can someone help me? Thanks!!

*---------------*

Here I am again to show the final (working!!) result of your friendly help:

At least, I used Sam's version cause it was just for what i was looking for. I really appreciate the other answers - specially 'cause now I have more stuff to think about for the next tries.

Sam's code worked just awesome... the only trouble I had was, that after using the array, it only printed out 'December' as months.

So I looked over again the code and after 2 hours of seek and try, I found the point of trouble. It was nested in the following line:

```
$this_month = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $row['get_month']) );
```

Changing it (It's logic, but for me as greenhorn it toke me a while) to:

```
$this_month = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month['get_month']) );
```

Now everything work fine. Just how I expected. So this is the working final code:

```
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT YEAR(date) AS get_year, MONTH(date) AS get_month, COUNT(*) AS entries FROM blogdata GROUP BY get_year, get_month ORDER BY date ASC") or die('No response from database.');


    $entries = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $entries[$row['get_year']][] = $row;
}

    foreach($entries as $year => $months) {
  echo '<dl>';
  echo '<dt>Entries from &nbsp;'. $year . '</dt>';


    foreach($months as $month) {
    $this_month = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month['get_month']) );

  echo '<dd><a href="archives.php?month='. $month['get_month'] .'">Entries from &nbsp;'. $this_month . '&nbsp;</a>(' . $month['entries'] . ')</dd>';

  }

  echo '</dl>';


}
```

Thanks to all again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the simplest way is something along these lines:

```
$entries = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $entries[$row['get_year']][] = $row;
}

foreach($entries as $year => $months) {
  echo '<dl>';
  echo '<dt>Entries from &nbsp;'. $year . '</dt>';

  echo '<dd>';
  foreach($months as $month) {\
    $this_month = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $row["get_month"]) );

    echo '<a href="archives.php?month='. $month['get_month'] .'">Entries from &nbsp;'. $this_month . '&nbsp;</a>(' . $month['entries'] . ')';
  }
  echo '</dd></dl>';


}
```

That HTML markup isn't ideal, but you should get the idea.

Comment: OMG that's it :D I was stumbling around the foreach myself but I did not find the right association. Thank you so much for the great and fast answer!

Comment: BTW - Safka's right, you need to group by the year as well.  Otherwise, you'll mash each calendar month's entries together across all years.

Comment: Thanks again! I'll check the other codes and try to find a good solution that will clean up my code a bit. Very helpful, guys!

Comment: When the day of the month is after the 28th, date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $row["get_month"]) ) will return 'March' even if the value of $row["get_month"] is 2. To fix it, change it to date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month['get_month'], 1) )

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your query to group by year and month, not only month:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    YEAR(date) AS get_year, 
    MONTH(date) AS get_month, 
    COUNT(*) AS entries 
FROM blogdata 
GROUP BY get_year, get_month 
ORDER BY date ASC"
```

I don't remember old mysql API, so here's code with [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/book.pdo.php) (untested, but should work after fixing potential typos)

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db', 'user', 'password');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//group results by year *
$groupped = array();
foreach ($results as $record) {
    $groupped[$record['get_year']] = $record;
}

//print results
echo "<dl>";
foreach ($groupped as $year => $monthsRecords) {
    echo "<dt>$year</dt>";
    foreach ($monthsRecords as $record) {
        echo "<dd>{$record['get_month']} : {$record['entries']}</dd>";
    }
} 
echo "</dl>";
```

You could also try to simplify code by using PDO::FETCH_GROUP, as described in 
[fetchAll method doc](http://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php) but I never tried this one, so I won't give you code.

Comment: Thank you, I will realize the query correction and take a further look over your code. So thankful. :)

Comment: And very appreciated for the tip to group the get_year too. I would oversee that and wonder next year *laugh* Thanks :)

Comment: the 'bugs that will manifest the next year' are my favorite ones ;) maybe except the 'bugs that will manifest only in leap years'

Comment: I wonder how many 'bugs I'll still find after finishing this project *^^*

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$start_year =  date("Y")-10;
$end_year = date("Y");
for ($i=$start_year;$i<$end_year;$i++){
 $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT YEAR(date) AS get_year, MONTH(date) AS get_month, COUNT(*)    AS entries FROM blogdata where YEAR(date) = $i GROUP BY get_month ORDER BY date ASC"); or die('No response from database.');
   //execute your query here. get the 
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
      echo '<dl>';
    echo '<dt>Entries from &nbsp;'. $i . '</dt>';

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result )) {

       $get_year = $row["get_year"];
       $get_month = $row["get_month"];
        $entries = $row["entries"];

 // get month name
 $this_month = date( 'F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $row["get_month"]) );

  echo '<dd><a href="archives.php?month='. $get_month .'">Entries from &nbsp;'.   $this_month .  '&nbsp;</a>(' . $entries . ')</dd>';

 }
   echo '</dl>';
}
```

Comment: Thank you too for another solution :D I see I'll have lot to do tomorrow checking out all this, hehe.