# Show one title and multiple dates from sql query

Tags: php, sql

New to sql and php and trying to work through this one.  After reading several examples here, I still can't seem to get this done.  Right now I have the following query

```
$sql = "SELECT e.id, e.event_name, e.recurrence_id, e.start_date, e.venue_title FROM " . wp_events_detail . " e  WHERE e.recurrence_id <>0 or e.recurrence_id = 0 and is_active = 'Y' GROUP BY e.event_name, e.start_date"  ;
                $posts = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

                print("<ul>");
                foreach ($posts as $post)
                {
                    print('<li>'.$post->event_name.'|'.$post->event_desc.'<br/>');

                     print('</li>');
                    print($post->start_date. '~' .$post->venue_title.'<br/>'); 
                }
                print("</ul>");
```

This produces
Name of Class A
Start Date 1
Name of Class A
Start Date 2
Name of Class B
Start Date 1
Name of Class B
Start Date 2

what I would like is 
Name of Class A
Start Date 1
Start Date 2

Name of Class B
Start Date 1
Start Date 2

I know I need an array and define rows - Have tried several options with no luck.  Not understanding all the variables etc defined in this answer (which seems what I want this to do)

[Show year only once in archives loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9253070/show-year-only-once-in-archives-loop)

Any help greatly appreciated!  Even a point in the right direction;-)

Comment: You may want to clarify what database you are using (I'm assuming MySQL?)

Comment: yes. SQL database - on a WordPress set up running Event Espresso

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can adjust your for loop to be:

```
$lastseeneventname='';
foreach ($posts as $post){
   if($lastseeneventname!=$post->event_name){
      print('<li>'.$post->event_name.'|'.$post->event_desc.'<br/>');
      print('</li>');
      $lastseeneventname=$post->event_name;
   }
   print($post->start_date. '~' .$post->venue_title.'<br/>'); 
}
```

This will only print new `event_name`s once which is what, I think, you want.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I want the event name once - which I can do with GROUP BY on recurrence.id. But under each event name I would like the dates for each instance of that event.  i.e.
Event Name
October 25, 2012
November 7, 2012
etc

Comment: Without knowing your sql structure, I think my answer does that.  Or you can do a `group by` loop, and then for each event name, do a query for all the dates of that event. this would be more queries and thus technically slower.

Comment: geez - missed that date part at the bottom - perfect solution THANK YOU!

Comment: great, if you're happy, please consider upvoting my answer and selecting it as a correct answer. thanks!

Comment: Landon,  Tried to upvote your answer - it told me I needed at least a 15 score to do that:-/ and unsure how to mark your answer as the correct answer...